# The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx, .net-1.1

I am using the .NET web service to exchange the XML file over the secure channel i.e. using the SSL certificate. The web service is developed in vb.NET 1.1 and hosted on windows server 2000.

While sending the file I am getting the below error intermittently

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS.

Is there any setting I need to do on my server or could you please suggest me any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Perhaps server fault is a better place for this

Comment: Are you using valid SSL certificates?

Comment: @MichaëlHompus :- yes I am using valid SSL certificates.